# openpgp can't update large file

Tags: openpgp, openpgp.js

```
onmessage = async({data:{blob, privateKey},ports:[port]})=>{
  try {
      const fileArray = await blob.arrayBuffer();
      const uint8 = new Uint8Array(fileArray);
 
      var readableStream = new ReadableStream({
        start(controller) {
            controller.enqueue(uint8);
            controller.close();
        }
      });

    const privateKeyObj = await openpgp.readPrivateKey({ armoredKey: privateKey });
    const message = await openpgp.readMessage({ armoredMessage:readableStream });
    console.log("message", message);
    const { data: decrypted} = await openpgp.decrypt({
          message: message,
          decryptionKeys: privateKeyObj,
          format: 'binary',
          config: {allowUnauthenticatedStream: true }
    });
 
        port.postMessage({blob: new Blob([decrypted],{type: blob.type})})
    } catch (error) {
        port.postMessage({error: error})
    }
}
```

I use openpgp v5.5.0, now I can't find the way to read Message as readableStream. Can anyone sugget and help what wrong with my code